# Can't insert PDF as object into WORD

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, adobe-acrobat

I drag a `.pdf` file to a word document and get  -

[image]

```
The program used to created this object is AcroExch. That program is either not installed on your computer or it is not responding.

To edit this object, install AcroExch or ensure that any dialog boxes in AcroExch are closed.
```

I use `Adobe Acrobat X Version 10.1.2` and `Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010` .

The "Correct" answer suggested [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/452958) (first search result in google) didn't work for me and gave same error  .

Answer (score 2):

I found if I have other PDF files open while trying to insert a PDF into a Word document I get this message.  If I close all opened PDF files running in my background I am able to insert a PDF with no problem.  Not sure why but that was my solution for my laptop.  I have a desktop and I am able to run Adobe Acrobat and install PDF file into word with out having to close anything.  Could be in my settings in Acrobat.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? Copy the PDF's contents in a Word file? If you only have Adobe Reader, try marking all the text, copy it and paste to Word. You have to copy the images separately and then you have to spend some time to manually restore the original format of the document. If you have Adobe Acrobat you can simply export the PDF document to Word (provided is not locked). There are third party convert utilities as well, but I would prefer the official Adobe Acrobat for best conversion and fidelity to the original.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it still may concern:

### Workaround 1:

1. Open Adobe Reader.
2. From Edit menu select Preferences, Preferences dialog box appears.
3. Select General category on the list, uncheck or remove tick mark for “Enable protected mode at startup”
4. Simply Close and reopen the application and the embedded object should now open perfectly.

### Workaround 2:

If you are same way unlucky as me and still have this issue after applying workaround above, you can try following: ZIP PDF file and add ZIP archive into Word document

### Workaround 3:

Last option is install FoxIt PDF viewer and keep Adobe Reader as default one.

Only problem with "FoxIt workaround" is that PDF file is inserted with incorrect icon. To fix this in Insert -> Object -> Create from File -> click on "Change Icon..." -> "Browse..." -> locate your Adobe Reader binaries (for me it is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\acroRd32.exe).

Answer (score 0):

To insert the PDF into a word document you simply need to open Word select insert object, in the Object windows select the create from file tab and browse to the file you want to insert, select it now you need to tick on one of check boxes below depending on how you want the file to appear, if you want it to appear as an icon you both check boxes must be selected otherwise select just link to file.

Hope this solves your problem.

Sabelo Myeni

Answer (score 0):

While digging for escape routes facing the same issue, I figured this error could occur from a crashing adobe/acrobat program running in the background in Windows system.

Open task manager, and kill any "Acro*" **processes** and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the video to see insert pdf in word and fix the icon issue
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fks2Y9SN8Mg&t=39s

Comment: Good information

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

My pdf files were stored on OneDrive and the insert object didn't like it. Copied locally and they inserted just fine.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1159305)

Answer (score 0):

Found two separate issues which caused the issue of not being able to insert the PDF inside my Word document.

1. If either file (Word or PDF) were stored in MS Teams (SharePoint), then both had to be stored there or I would get the AcroArch error.
2. If the PDF file was corrupted (e.g., 0 byte file) it would result in the AcroArch error.